# Babylonjs, get the mesh that the point (x,y,z) point to one of it's faces

Tags: 3d, babylonjs

I have a 3D-point and I need to know if this point is in any mesh in my scene.

I found :

```
var pickResult = scene.pick(scene.pointerX, scene.pointerY);
```

but I need to pass a 3D-point not a pointer position.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you would need to keep an array containing all the meshes you need to check against.

```
var meshList = []; // List Containing all your meshes you want to check if the point is in
var point = new BABYLON.Vector3(x,y,z); // Where x,y,z are replaced with your coordinates

for(i=0; i<meshList.length; i++){
    if(meshList[i].intersectsPoint(point)){
        console.log("Your point is in a mesh");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scene.pickWithRay:

```
var rayPick1 = new BABYLON.Ray(origin, direction);
var meshFound1 = scene.pickWithRay(rayPick1, function (item) {

});
```